# mongodb:complex nested aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "60b22e1dbd46fa18a8308318"
    },
    "title": "basketball",
    "price": 12,
    "category": "Furniture",
    "description": "",
    "images": [
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/hadarush100/image/upload/v1622289949/nfg948x3zro6gbiuknrz.jpg"
    ],
    "categoryId": 1,
    "userId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
    "createdAt": 1622289948232,
    "chats": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "createdAt": 1622289948232,
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "createdAt": 1622289948232,
            "senderId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
            "text": "Hello, Im the seller of this product."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "createdAt": 1622289948232,
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "createdAt": 1622289948232,
            "senderId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
            "text": "Hello, Im the seller of this product."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and i want to find specific document (by _id), then dive into specific chat in this document (by id), than use $lookup for replacing the "senderId" property in each message with a "sender" property that contains the full sender details (as a user), that exist in another collection (users). the result needs to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "60b22e1dbd46fa18a8308318"
    },
    "title": "basketball",
    "price": 12,
    "category": "Furniture",
    "description": "",
    "images": [
      "http://res.cloudinary.com/hadarush100/image/upload/v1622289949/nfg948x3zro6gbiuknrz.jpg"
    ],
    "categoryId": 1,
    "userId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
    "createdAt": 1622289948232,
    "chats": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "createdAt": 1622289948232,
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "createdAt": 1622289948232,
            "sender": {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927"
                },
                "username": "hadar",
                "email": "hadarushha@gmail.com",
                "profileImgUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/79.jpg",
                "createdAt": 1621956168518
            },
            "text": "Hello, Im the seller of this product."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "createdAt": 1622289948232,
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "createdAt": 1622289948232,
            "sender": {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927"
                },
                "username": "hadar",
                "email": "hadarushha@gmail.com",
                "profileImgUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/79.jpg",
                "createdAt": 1621956168518
            },
            "text": "Hello, Im the seller of this product."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: do you just want to get that data as an answer to the query or do you actually want to modify the original collection (I assume it's called Products) by adding data from the Users collection?

In the first case, it is a very simple aggregation.
In the second, are you aware that you would significantly change the db scheme?

Depending on your answer I give you the way to do it.

Comment: The first one. For querying propose

Comment: could you verify my solution?

Comment: it would be nice if when someone posts a possible solution to your question you deign to at least answer or give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation:

- `$match` to filter only selected document (_id)
- `$unwind` multiple time to transform arrays into objects
- `$lookup` to query external collection (users)
- `$group` in reverse order

I assumed that your collections are more or less like this (next time, post both collections and also an example on a working playground)

```
db={
  "products": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b22e1dbd46fa18a8308318"
      },
      "title": "basketball",
      "price": 12,
      "category": "Furniture",
      "description": "",
      "images": [
        "http://res.cloudinary.com/hadarush100/image/upload/v1622289949/nfg948x3zro6gbiuknrz.jpg"
      ],
      "categoryId": 1,
      "userId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
      "createdAt": 1622289948232,
      "chats": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "createdAt": 1622289948232,
          "messages": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "createdAt": 1622289948232,
              "senderId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
              "text": "Hello, Im the seller of this product."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "createdAt": 1622289948232,
          "messages": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "createdAt": 1622289948232,
              "senderId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
              "text": "Hello, Im the seller of this product."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b22e1dbd46fa18a8308319"
      },
      "title": "volleyball",
      "price": 8,
      "category": "Furniture",
      "description": "",
      "images": [
        "http://res.cloudinary.com/hadarush100/image/upload/v1622289949/nfg948x3zro6gbiuknrz.jpg"
      ],
      "categoryId": 1,
      "userId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
      "createdAt": 1622289948232,
      "chats": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "createdAt": 1622289948232,
          "messages": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "createdAt": 1622289948232,
              "senderId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927",
              "text": "Hello, Im the seller of this product."
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "createdAt": 1622289948232,
          "messages": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "createdAt": 1622289948232,
              "senderId": "60ad16493062eb11141d4928",
              "text": "Hello, Im the seller of this product."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ad16493062eb11141d4927"
      },
      "username": "hadar",
      "email": "hadarushha@gmail.com",
      "profileImgUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/79.jpg",
      "createdAt": 1621956168518
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ad16493062eb11141d4928"
      },
      "username": "test",
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "profileImgUrl": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/49.jpg",
      "createdAt": 1621956168528
    },
    
  ]
}
```

And here is the working aggregation:

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b22e1dbd46fa18a8308319"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$chats"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$chats.messages"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "chats.messages.senderIdObjId": {
        "$convert": {
          "input": "$chats.messages.senderId",
          "to": "objectId",
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "chats.messages.senderIdObjId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "chats.messages.sender"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$chats.messages.sender"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$chats.id",
      "messages": {
        "$push": "$chats.messages"
      },
      "allFields": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "allFields.chats.messages": "$messages"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$allFields"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "chats": {
        "$push": "$chats"
      },
      "allFields": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "allFields.chats": "$chats"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$allFields"
  },
  
])
```

[Working Playground here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S3Jw1hAjF-X)

Comment: Just a little note: I used $convert because in your collection externail ObjIds were saved as strings. This is a bad practice, I suggest you to store directly ObjId and not strings.